# jQuery: function attached to image with .load() never gets called in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, load, jquery

I'm attaching a function to an image to be executed when the image is loaded:

```
this.img.load( function(self){ return function(){
   self.ready = true;
   // more code
}; }(this) );
```

`this` is an object, `this.img` is the image object. In Internet Explorer, that function never gets called. It works fine in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

I'm not very familiar with IE and I'd really appreciate help. Full source [here](http://www.dcfoto.de/new/) (line 125).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to assign the load-method before assigning the src-attribute to the img-object.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks! Now let's fix all the other IE-only-bugs :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug.  You first assign the src(the loading-process of the image starts now). Then you assign some css. Later you assign the load-method. If the image is loaded before you assign the load-method, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

@travelboy. Jquery has a load method.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Have you checked 4 that particular event?

```
$('img.userIcon').load(function(){
  if($(this).height() > 100) {
    $(this).addClass('bigImg');
  }
});
```

Comment: In fact I am using the jQuery method you mention. At least that's what I thought. Or should I write `$(this.img).load(…)`? I have a direct reference to the image object, so I thought I don't need the $.

Comment: You need to specify always the $, there is a difference between using $ and not using. what you sometimes do is use jQuery instead of $, but in other cases the unique way is to implement $ in your Jquery context. Check Jquery documentation for more info. if you wanna search all your images and attach a photo to them you show first do something like: $("img").each(function(){}); . Don't forget that.

Comment: Exactly, you need to call jQuery on the DOM element to get a jQuery object.

Comment: Hmmm, if I attach the load() handler before setting src (as suggested by Dr.Molle), it works. Even without the $. And in Safari/Chrome/Firefox it worked right away. But I guess `this.img` is already a jQuery object, since I created it by calling `this.img = $('<div>')`. Thanks for the info!